# Connect one monitor(mouse and keyboard connected to it) to 2 pc

Tags: keyboard, display, mouse, desktop-computer, usb-c

Can I use one monitor (keyboard and mouse connected to it) with MacBook Pro (connected by USB-C) and PC (connected by HDMI/DP + USB A-B) just switching source on monitor? Will keyboard and mouse work for each selected source this way(without any external switchers)?

Or i will need to unplug some cables from monitor to work with 1st or 2nd source that keyboard and mouse work properly?